# Visual Studio 2010 builds fine in Debug And release mode but not with TFS continuous integration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, continuous-integration

It throws an error about "AjaxControlToolKit" not being found, even though I have referenced them in my solution. My solution builds successfully from VS 2010, but not when I use the TFS Continuous Build Integration. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Its been sometime, I used AjaxToolKit but I remember, it has to be installed in the machine. Have you installed AjaxControlToolkit in the build server.

Comment: I haven't "installed" it. I've just referenced the DLL and it builds fine when building with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Which version of .Net framework you are targeting? Did you reference the dll from GAC? or is the dll present in your application bin folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All referenced third party controls must be available to the TFS Build service.  This means that you should create a folder (I like to use "assemblies") and place those controls in that folder.

Then check the folder into source control just like everything else.  Finally, your app should reference the assemblies in THAT folder as opposed to any other location.

Other than GAC'ing them (which I absolutely do not recommend) it's the only way.

---

Next, you mention a "refresh" folder in your comments to Pharabus's answer.  I'm going to assume this means that you have a "Web Site Project".  You should seriously consider converting this to a "Web Application Project".  Web Site Projects have a tendency to screw over your assembly references by retargeting them when you reopen the project.  Which you absolutely do NOT want when using TFS Build.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't have a say in that respect

Comment: I think the solution is like you said. Either converting to web application and getting rid of .refresh files, or putting the DLL in the GAC (which poses security risks). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you reference the ajaxcontroltoolkit from? it may be available on the development machine but not on the TFS Server where the build happens

Comment: The TFS server and the ajaxcontroltoolkit bin are both on my server

Comment: not sure I understand you, on the dev machine where do you refrence the ajaxcontroltoolkit from, is it just in the bin folder, if so is it checked into TFS in the bin folder too so that when TFS Server pushes the file to the build directory it is there to be referenced?

Comment: The ajax control is in the bin folder on my machine. The TFS server is also running on my machine with Continuous Build Integration. When I build the solution from VS it works fine, but it doesn't work with CBI

Comment: But TFS will build in a build folder (defined in the build scripts) so, if the ajaxcontroltoolkit is not somewhere that TFS can get it (GAC, checked in the same relative folder etc) it will fail

Comment: I see what you're saying. It's running the build off of a project in TFS source control which only has refresh files and the bin is not available to it. But DLL files shouldn't be added to TFS, what's another way around that?

Comment: DLL files can be added and not cause issues. But do not add them from the /Bin directory of the project using them. See Chris' answer below (top half)

Comment: Chris's answer below is the way to go, he uses assemblies I like ThirdPartyFiles but there is no issue with referenced dlls in TFS, the bin folder should be avoided though